# Can we use Photoshop/GIMP to create black lines in nine-patch (9.png) images?

Tags: android, photoshop, gimp, nine-patch

Android SDK tool draw9patch is soooo slow when I have to create a nine-patch from a full image (image for backgrounds) because it does not allow quick drawing of black line from top to bottom (like we are used in Photoshop or Gimp), but I have to paint each pixel. So waste of time. I think you know what I am talking about.

So, has anyone tried to draw black lines in Photoshop/GIMP taking care that you do not fill the end pixels?  Will Android SDK treat them as a regular 9 PNG images?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

9.png is just .png - You can use any of you favorite tool just 1px border must be transparent or filled with black and extension must be set to .9.png

Comment: This problem is generally known - just read android 9.path documentation.

Comment: Just put some icon on transparent background, paint some pixels on border with black (0xFF000000) pencil and put it into your android project it's much faster than discussion on SOF. You can also search for 9.png photoshop and read one of first 100 returned answers.

Answer (score 3):

There's this web tool - Simple Nine-patch Generator - which I find quite handy:

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

Comment: I think this reply it totally not needed. this tool is so elementary.

Comment: Hey @sandalone, just sharing for anyone (like me) not versed in Gimp/Photoshop and wanting to quickly add the nine-patch black lines to existing images. I find the online _Simple Nine-Patch Generator_ quicker to use than _draw9patch_.

Answer (score 0):

I use Better9patch tool then I test them SDK's 9patch tool. But if you create 9patch with 1px border you should retouch them with PS or etc.. tools